# How to dynamically create object that implements a custom interface in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Mentioned below  is the hierarchy of my files. Inside Mypackage folder there are subfolders for each database implementation with respective py files.

```
mypackage
      |
      |_  connectioninterface.py  ( Interface Class)
      |
      |__ SnowFlakePakage
                |
                |_snowflakeimpl.py    (Implementation Class)
      |
      |__ MysqlPakage
                |
                |_mysqlimpl.py    (Implementation Class)
      |
      |__ PostgresPackage
                |
                |_postgresimpl.py    (Implementation Class)

      |
      |__ mainPackage
                |
                |_main.py    (driving  Class)
```

Below is the definition of classes and interfaces.

**connectioninterface.py**

```
from abc import ABC, abstract method
class Connection(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_connection(self,cnx_info):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def close_cnx(self,cnx):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def execute_query(self,qry):
        pass
```

**snowflakeimpl.py**

```
 from mypackage.connectioninterface import Connection
class SnowFlakeConn(Connection):
     def __init__(self):
         ....
         ....

    def get_connection(self, cnx_info):
        "logic for getting connection"

    def close_cnx(self, cnx):
        "logic for closing connection"

    def execute_query(self, qry):
        "logic for executing query"
```

**mysqlimpl.py**

```
 from mypackage.connectioninterface import Connection
class MysqlConn(Connection):
     def __init__(self):
         ....
         ....

    def get_connection(self, cnx_info):
        "logic for getting connection"

    def close_cnx(self, cnx):
        "logic for closing connection"

    def execute_query(self, qry):
        "logic for executing query"
```

Like wise I have implementation class for other databases. Now in the main method I need to create the object dynamically for the implementation class based on the parameter that I pass to main function. If I execute the following, the main.py should dynamically create the object for the given class.

```
py main.py "SnowFlakeConn" 
             or 
    py main.py "MysqlConn"
             or
    py main.py "PostgresConn"
```

Also, if at all I need to add support to SqlServer and Oracle Database in future, I should be able  to develop the SqlServer and Oracle Implementation classes and deploy them without having to touch any of the previous modules not even main.py.

Can we create the object dynamically in the main function by passing the ClassName for which the object should be created and trigger the functions respective to its class?

getattr(<module_name>, class_name) will work to dynamically create the class but it expects the module_name to be imported in the main.py file. In future if I want to add another database implementation, the mainfile will also have to be changed for importing the mysql module, which I want to avoid. we are creating an application and this is packaged and a wheel is created for deployment. So any further implementation classes for any other databases should go as connectors as part of new wheels but not to recompile the previous wheel. Hope I made sense. Kindly provide a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you don't want to manually specify all the modules to be imported then you need to use a convention, e.g. if all the modules `snowflakeimpl`, `mysqlimpl` live inside a `db_implementations` package that only contains impl modules, then you can just import that and iterate over the submodules

Comment: a simpler idea would be to put all the `SnowFlakeConn`, `MysqlConn` etc classes in a single module so you can directly import that module and getattr the class you need

Comment: Unfortunately, putting all the implementation classes wont work. if i have to add new implementations in future, I have to append the module with new implementation class and recompile the whole application again. If we would have not created a wheel, your solution works. But my management is asking to create wheel

Comment: but you have to create a new wheel when new classes are added anyway?

Comment: to publish new implementations as separate wheel packages have a look at plugins https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/creating-and-discovering-plugins/

Comment: but you have to create a new wheel when new classes are added anyway? 
    -- Yes, but the new classes goes as a new wheel. Old ones should not be touched is what my lead says.

Answer (score 0):

importlib package solved the problem. For all the classes which implemented the interface, I have put each implementation in a separate package and created the wheel file. Installed the wheel file. Now from the main program i am passing the packagename and modulename as a string. The module is imported dynamically and the object can be created dynamically to any implementation class without the need to make changes any where. In future if I need to introduce oracle implementation class, I will create wheel for oracle and pass the pkg and module name as string to main function using commandline arguments and it will create the object for Oracle Implementation class.

```
import importlib

mod = importlib.import_module('mysqlpkg.mysql')
print(getattr(mod,'MysqlConn')())

output: 
<mysqlpkg.mysql.MysqlConn object at 0x000001D7EAF2A460>
```